# How to ask if a person has done/had breakfast?

Tags: questions

Is it "Did you do breakfast?"
or
"Did you have/had breakfast?"

Answer (score 18):

It would usually be either *“Did you have breakfast?”* or *“Have you had breakfast?”*  Also fine are *“Did you eat… ?”* and *“Have you eaten… ?”*

If it is — say — mid-morning, and you want to know if someone has already eaten today, then *“Have you had/eaten breakfast?”* (possibly “…yet?”) is probably the more natural form (since they might still have the breakfast in question), but either is fine.  If you’re asking about a previous day, or asking in the afternoon (so that it’s too late for them to have that breakfast), then it should be *“Did you have/eat breakfast?”*

To *do* breakfast (or any other meal) has a slightly different connotation: not just eating the meal, but specifically meeting someone for it, usually to discuss business.  Unless you’re specifically talking about this situation, *Did you do breakfast?* is probably not what you want.

[Google ngrams data for corroboration.](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=did+you+have+breakfast%2Chave+you+had+breakfast%2Cdid+you+do+breakfast%2Chave+you+done+breakfast%2Cdid+you+eat+breakfast%2Chave+you+eaten+breakfast&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: "Breakfast" is also a verb, so you could ask "Have you breakfasted?" - this usage is less common but more refreshing for that very reason!

Comment: @Waggers the verb *break* in relation to the noun *fast* is still sometimes found rather than the compound-verb you give; "Have you broken your fast?" It's much rarer now than it once was, but not completely dead.

Comment: Perhaps this could be formatted in such a way that no possible confusion could arise? It's 29,473 views so far, it's worth that little effort. There's also the "Have you already had breakfast?" form, and it's done. I can't think of any other (normal) alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have your breakfast? Did is telling that it is past so there is no need to put another past word for it.

You can use "I ate my breakfast./ I had my breakfast."  Also you can say : I breakfasted

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one would say, "Have you had breakfast?" or "Did you have breakfast [yet]?" to ask if someone has eaten breakfast on a particular day or morning.

When used with breakfast, *do* can also mean *eat* (besides *make*, etc). However, this usage has more to do with frequency than anything else. Thus, the following example is valid: "I don't do breakfast on Sundays." Another: "Did you do breakfast today?" In fact, you might notice that, in regular conversation, *do breakfast* is mostly used in the first person and rarely in the interrogative.

It is unidiomatic (but not incorrect) to say, "Have you done breakfast?" to ask if someone has *eaten* breakfast.

Answer (score 0):

HAD BREAKFAST is one of the most common way of query we often see.
if you want to know a person has eaten its ideal to ask " have you eaten " or "did you eat "...
the question is to be asked in its right way .. :)

Answer (score -1):

Or if you are interested in what they ate for breakfast, one could ask "What did you break fast with?" Likewise if you are offering food, "What would you like to break fast with?"

Comment: That's not what the question is about, though.