# What is the difference between these two question structure and which one is correct 1) How did you get my number? 2) How have you got my number?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two question structure and which one is correct

1. How **did** you get my number?
2. How **have** you got my number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ask if a person has done/had breakfast?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38810/how-to-ask-if-a-person-has-done-had-breakfast) Same difference as *Did you do it?* and *Have you done it?* (effectively, *none*).

Comment: Are you asking about the syntax?

Comment: Both grammatical. The second would probably be unusual in the US, and in the UK,  probably slightly more confrontational than the first (already, without hedging, slightly confrontational).